# How to unify a split image in python?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I have an image that I loaded using cv2. I rescaled the image, converted it into the YCbCR color space. I split the image into its 3 components.

```
    image_rescaled.shape
    Output[8]: (2016, 1512, 3)
    Y, Cr, Cb = cv2.split(image_rescaled)
    Y.shape
    Output[9]: (2016, 1512)
```

Once I performed whatever operations I needed to I wanted to merge the three components back. How can I do so? I'm getting stuck at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCV has a [`cv2.merge()`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=cv2.merge#cv2.merge) function which does this. It can merge an arbitrary number of channels. Additionally, [`np.dstack()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html) will do the same thing.

You can also use `np.split()` or `np.dsplit()` to split your three-channel image into separate channels; but this is *very* slightly different than the `cv2.split()`; check the shapes of the resulting operations (in particular, the shape of a single channel after being split):

With OpenCV functions:

```
>>> img = cv2.imread('image.png')
>>> b, g, r = cv2.split(img)
>>> bgr = cv2.merge([b, g, r])
>>> img.shape
(508, 640, 3)
>>> b.shape
(508, 640)
>>> bgr.shape
(508, 640, 3)
```

With numpy functions:

```
>>> img = cv2.imread('image.png')
>>> b, g, r = np.dsplit(img, 3)
>>> bgr = np.merge([b, g, r])
>>> img.shape
(508, 640, 3)
>>> b.shape
(508, 640, 1)
>>> bgr.shape
(508, 640, 3)
```

Either way, after being merged with OpenCV or numpy, the resulting shape is what you want. Note that both can be used to stack arbitrary matrices however many channels you want. This can be helpful for stacking an image sequence for processing or storing. You can even stack single channel images with e.g. multichannel images (or, probably more common, to add a channel or multiple channels onto an image stack):

```
>>> bgr = cv2.merge([b, g, r, img])
>>> bgr.shape # b, g, r each 1ch, img is 3ch, should be 6ch total
(508, 640, 6)
>>> bgr = np.dstack([b, g, r, img])
>>> bgr.shape
(508, 640, 6)
```

So the next question would be "is there any reason to use one over the other?" Since the output is the same and they both work on inputs that we may want, the only other main concern is speed. And (surprisingly to me), it turns out that OpenCV's `cv2.merge()` function ends up being just shy of an order of magnitude faster:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('image.png')
b, g, r = cv2.split(img)

import timeit
times = range(50000)

start_time = timeit.default_timer()
for t in times:
    A = cv2.merge([b, g, r])
print("cv2.merge: ", timeit.default_timer() - start_time, "s")

start_time = timeit.default_timer()
for t in times:
    A = np.dstack([b, g, r])
print("np.dstack: ", timeit.default_timer() - start_time, "s")
```

> cv2.merge:  3.0349163499922724 s
>
> np.dstack:  22.386054433998652 s

Comment: You've a nice answer, so I'll delete mine.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. It helped a lot.

Comment: @SanketWagh if it helped you out, would you mind marking the answer as accepted? Otherwise let me know if you have other questions with this.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Thanks for the support; I originally was just going to leave `cv2.merge()` as a comment on your answer but I decided to time the differences and ended up writing up this post when I saw the large difference with `cv2.merge()`.